# How to pick data from JSON response in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

I have a JSON response in below format and I want to pick data from it in React. I tried it below way but not successful so far and getting `TypeError: valuesArray.map is not a function`. Can anyone take a look what to change here.

**Code:**

```
const valuesArray = JSON.parse(data);
const users = valuesArray.map((u) => (
          <tr key={u.builder}>
            <td>{u.builder}</td> 
            <td>{u.account_id}</td>
          </tr>
        ));
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "44876989": [
    {
      "Key": "builder",
      "Value": "test@outlook.com"
    },
    {
      "Key": "account_id",
      "Value": "030303"
    }
  ],
  "2207966": [
    {
      "Key": "builder",
      "Value": "aabc@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "Key": "account_id",
      "Value": "002235"
    }
  ],
  "5393": [
    {
      "Key": "builder",
      "Value": "xyz@abc.com"
    },
    {
      "Key": "account_id",
      "Value": "000mmm"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is valuesArray? Is that the JSON?

Comment: If valuesArray is that JSON, it's an object not array.

Comment: Yeah I am just parsing the JSON response in valuesArray `const valuesArray = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Since the JSON is an object after you parse it `map()` doesn't make any sense to do here. You can either transform the JSON into a shape that works with your `map()` code or you can change the `map()` to work with the existing shape of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an object that contain a arrays of properties. You should transform it to an array of objects, and then render it.

**Note**: You should transform the object to an renderable array, when you get to info from the API, or when you take it from the redux store (using a selector).

```js
const Example = ({ values }) => {
  const valuesArray = Object.values(values)
    .map(arr =>
      Object.fromEntries(
        arr.map(({ Key, Value }) => [Key, Value])
      )
    );

  const users = valuesArray.map((u) => (
    <tr key={u.builder}>
      <td>{u.builder}</td> 
      <td>{u.account_id}</td>
    </tr>
  ));

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {users}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const values = {"5393":[{"Key":"builder","Value":"xyz@abc.com"},{"Key":"account_id","Value":"000mmm"}],"2207966":[{"Key":"builder","Value":"aabc@gmail.com"},{"Key":"account_id","Value":"002235"}],"44876989":[{"Key":"builder","Value":"test@outlook.com"},{"Key":"account_id","Value":"030303"}]};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example values={values} />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Although you can render it directly by destructuring the `Value` from each object in properties array, if the order of the properties is maintained, but that might be prone to errors:

```js
const Example = ({ values }) => {
  const users = Object.values(values)
    .map(([{ Value: builder }, { Value: account_id }]) => (
      <tr key={builder}>
        <td>{builder}</td> 
        <td>{account_id}</td>
      </tr>
    ));

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {users}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const values = {"5393":[{"Key":"builder","Value":"xyz@abc.com"},{"Key":"account_id","Value":"000mmm"}],"2207966":[{"Key":"builder","Value":"aabc@gmail.com"},{"Key":"account_id","Value":"002235"}],"44876989":[{"Key":"builder","Value":"test@outlook.com"},{"Key":"account_id","Value":"030303"}]};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example values={values} />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Just one more question what if i want to get the value 5393 , 44876989 as well along with corresponding values  in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with an object which contains arrays I have come up with a simple logic to extract the data you need,

```
const valuesArray  = {
    44876989: [
      {
        Key: 'builder',
        Value: 'test@outlook.com',
      },
      {
        Key: 'account_id',
        Value: '030303',
      },
    ],
    2207966: [
      {
        Key: 'builder',
        Value: 'aabc@gmail.com',
      },
      {
        Key: 'account_id',
        Value: '002235',
      },
    ],
    5393: [
      {
        Key: 'builder',
        Value: 'xyz@abc.com',
      },
      {
        Key: 'account_id',
        Value: '000mmm',
      },
    ],
  };

 
  return (
    <table>
      {/* mapping through the keys of the object. */}
      {Object.keys(valuesArray).map((a) => {  
        {/* each item here is an array. Find the object you need */}
        const builder =   valuesArray[a].find(v => v.Key === "builder").Value; 
        const account_id =   valuesArray[a].find(v => v.Key === "account_id").Value;   
       
        return (
          <tr key={builder}>
            <td>{builder}</td>
            <td>{account_id}</td>           
          </tr>
        ); 
      })}
    </table>
  );
```